# Flicker-free JComponent rendering within a Swing event handler

Tags: java, swing, animation, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

I'm writing a simple Java Swing application that is designed as a demo for a course.  The purpose of the program is to visualize the progress of a recursive method (specifically, a recursive solution to a maze).  I'd like to be able to update the appearance of the JComponent as the recursive method executes, so from the perspective of Swing the updates can't be triggered individually from a Timer class, which I gather is the usual method for animations.

My first thought was just to call repaint() whenever I want to redraw the visualization.  But the recursive method itself is called in the event handler of a JButton, which means all the calls to repaint() are delayed until the event handler terminates -- and all I get to see is the last frame of the animation.  I found that I can get the drawing to happen immediately if I call update() instead, like this:

```
getRootPane().getContentPane().update(getGraphics());
try {
    Thread.sleep(25);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

This almost works, except that the animation flickers.  I know that Swing is double-buffered, but apparently getGraphics gives me the active buffer rather than the back buffer.  I can't see any methods that would give me access to the back buffer.

So I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to repaint the component in the middle of the recursion and give me a flicker-free animation.  Is there a way to activate the built-in double-buffering while an event handler is executing?  Would it be better to try to implement my own buffering system?  Or is what I'm trying to do just not possible/advisable with Swing?

(As a final note, this is my first post here.  I've tried to write a good question, but if I'm missing anything please let me know nicely and I'll try to do better next time.  Thanks!)

Comment: I think you've included everything :) although it may be helpful to see the recursion to try to pinpoint a spot where a repaint() might be squeezed in. You may end up with some conditionals in the recursion and/or repaint so that it is only called when it is appropriate.

Comment: Why not maintain a reference to the previous buffer and update with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should [not be executing long-running actions in the Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), and I assume that's one reason your animation flickers.

So I'd suggest starting off a thread that executes your recursive method when pressing the button (and maybe deactivate it until the work is done).

To render the animation, you may either call `myComponent.repaint()` from within your recursive method or you start a Swing Timer (Thanks to @mKorbel for poiting that out) which basically looks like this:

```
ActionListener repaintTrigger = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          myComponent.repaint();
      }
};
new Timer(25, repaintTrigger).start();
```

I recommend the latter approach, as your recursive method should probably not know anything about a Swing component (unless you decouple it via a "ProgressListener" or something).

As it seems your no mere beginner, I just gave some hints on what to do. If you need more input, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks; that gave me enough to go on.  Key insight was that running the recursion on another thread would allow repaint() to be used normally.  I like your other suggestions too, although I'm trying to keep the rest of the code simple so that the recursion remains the focus.

Comment: not, never (sure could be  works), but to use Swing Timer for todays Java6/7 instead

Comment: @mKorbel Haven't been doing much Swing those last years, thanks for pointing me to [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know if this works but.
I would try to make it multi-threaded and separate the recursion from the graphics. I don't know if this works on java but it did work for me in C#.